# Weird Windows 10 batch compatability issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, variable-expansion

I just upgraded Windows 10. But the batch file I wrote not works completely. Same coding was working with Windows 7. That's the piece of code.

```
:BASLA
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "s=DIR D:\Diziler /S /Q ^|FIND /i "Administrators" ^|findstr /m /i "HDTV" ^|findstr /m /i "\.mkv$""
for /f "Tokens=5,6*" %%f in ('%s%') do (
    set FULLNAME=%%f
    set ENDTEXT=!FULLNAME:*0p=!
    call set TRIMMEDNAME=%%FULLNAME:!ENDTEXT!=%%

for /r D:\Diziler\ %%g in (*) do echo %%~nxg >> %tmp%\altyazi.txt 

>nul findstr /c:"!FULLNAME:~0,-4!.srt" %tmp%\altyazi.txt  && (
>>%tmp%\list.txt echo !TRIMMEDNAME!*
) || (
>>%tmp%\list.txt echo !TRIMMEDNAME!
)
)
)
```

First part is working as usual. altyazi.txt gives the right output. But when it comes the list.txt all the outputs are Echo is off. I have never seen something like this. Works with 7 but doesn't work with 10.

Comment: There's apparently an unneeded closing `)` at the end, what happens if you remove it?

Comment: I just noticed it but nothing happens when I remove it.

Comment: Obviously `TRIMMEDNAME` is empty, so you should check what content is in `FULLNAME` and `ENDTEXT`. Then you should change your SET syntax to `set "FULLNAME=%%f"` and `set "ENDTEXT=!FULLNAME:*0p=!"` to avoid problems with trailing spaces. Probably the output of `DIR /Q` has changed

Comment: You were right. FULLNAME shows "Administrator" as data. But it shouldn't. How can I make it right?

Comment: It would be a good idea to compare the output of DIR /Q for both systems and post it here, but please only for one file

Comment: Your comment gave me an idea. I think that Windows 10 and Windows 7 are giving different columns when DIR listing. So I changed tokens 5,6 to 6,7 problem solved!

Comment: Since you found the solution of your problem, please post it as an answer and accept it, so the question does not remain open in the SO database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 and Windows 7 are giving different columns when DIR listing. Changing the tokens would solve the problem.